# Best way for querying database periodically which updates frequently (every min) and process the data for further usage

Tags: c#, .net, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, schedule

My requirements are as below:

I need to periodically query either a SQL or Oracle database (depending on a configuration) to check if there is any change (Add/Modify/Update any rows) to data in some set of tables (20 to 30). Query/Get some of the data from these tables and do further processing.

Here most of the further processing is already done in a Web Service so I have to pass some data obtained for above set of tables to this Web Service.

To achieve this, I am thinking of creating a Windows Service/Console app to check if there is any additions/deletions/updates to required set of tables and pass the data to Web Service as requested. This Windows Service is configured to get data from either Oracle/SQL using Entity framework. And in order to periodically query the database, I am thinking of using Task Scheduler to schedule this, say for every hour as the source database frequently changes.

I am not sure whether this is the right approach. Looking for inputs. I cannot use triggers and my app/scheduler should be common for both Oracle and SQL Databases.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/t9x04ed2(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: How are you planning on detecting the change? is there a last_update date in each of these tables. Polling all the data in this many tables regularly and comparing to previous would be terribly inefficient. Would you be allowed to read the transaction logs for these DBs? Is it completely impossible for you to interface with whatever app is doing the insert/update/delete? Without using the a trigger/server event/app event or the presence of a modified column this will not be pretty

Comment: Yes there is last_updated date in all of these tables. I am thinking of storing a time when I previously polled the database and use this time each time to compare with last updated date of all rows in the tables I am using, and get the required info. Transaction logs I am not sure. But for interfacing with the app that does insert/delete/update is completely not possible (Well here what does insert is not a single app, as of now 4 apps which may extend also). Still, using last updated time is not a good approach I believe. Any help would be deeply appreciated.